# Mysql query to select if a user's friends list is the logged in user's friend

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the friend list of a user profile. That's easy because of the schema I did.

Here is the table I did and demo data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f78cf7/2

[image]

If I want to get the friend of user id 1, I would run `select * from friends where user_id = 1` and I will get friends of this user. This is will return only first row with friend_id = 21.

Now how can I know if user id 30 is also a friend with id 21 in same query? How can I get the status column in same query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ee7f52638b71bd3d115ef58eed180b2)**

```
select f.user_id,f.friend_id,f.status
from friends f join friends f1 on f.id=f1.id+1
where f.status='Friend' and f1.status='Friend'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can search both sides. For example:

```
select *
from friends where user_id = 30 and friend_id = 21 and status = 'Friend'
                or user_id = 21 and friend_id = 30 and status = 'Friend'
```